# Spawn werkzeug interactive console with stacktrace from frame

Tags: python, web-services, exception, signals, werkzeug

I know it is possible to spawn an interactive console in werkzeug upon exception raise. This yields an interactive console with stacktrace and is exactly what I need. The environment of the problem is that I want to be able to, upon SIGUSR2 signal, spawn the interactive console to debug what might have caused our massive qa code to hang during execution.

For a smaller project it might suffice to let a raised exception propagate up to top level and handle the start of the webservice there and simply reraise the same error in one of the routes to kick the interactive console with the stacktrace.

However this is not an option for me, so my question is: Is there anyway to provide the stack frame to DebuggedApplication or construct an Exception from the stack frame (without loosing the context and stacktrace?

So far I've fiddled with **1**:

```
def handler(signum, frame):
    app = DebuggedApplication(application, evalex=True)
    run_simple('', 9998, app, use_debugger=True)
```

And **2**: 
        @Request.application
        def application(request):
            raise

```
    def handler(signum, frame):
        raise Exception('user requested interactive console')

    def main():
        try:
            signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR2, handler)
            ... some code kicking of tests ...
        except:
            run_simple('', 9998, application, use_debugger=True)
```

**1** only kicks off a interactive shell on localhost:9998/console (eq. to typing only python in terminal). And **2** is not possible because I cannot get the exception to percolate all the way to top level (without significant refactoring), and I don't want to handle this at multiple places. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can use alternative to werkzeug debugger? https://github.com/Kozea/wdb

Comment: Even though this question is old, but it's not a good idea to use Werkzeug's debugger in production. Real alternatives might be [Sentry](http://getsentry.com) or WDB.

Comment: Markus: ok, the intention was to use it internally in the QA process. Haven't gotten around to try out wdb yet, but I'll definitely give it a shot once I find the time! Thanks